# Feedback Level of the Info window

Tags: interface

I wonder if the level of feedback-detail in the blender info window can be "adjusted"?

At the moment, the info window shows only that "something" has been moved to <coordinates> or that "something" has been selected in the outliner.

For example undo steps aren't shown in info window, as are selections in viewport or specific details about which vertex has been selected in 'edit mode'.

Can I somehow "up the level of feedback" in the info window? I need to track certain actions while modelling.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you mean the _Info_ window selectable from all the editor windows which is meant to show the "Log of operations, warnings and error messages" (as the tool tip says) then I guess no, there is no way to "level it up", because it is basically just a log of what is happening internally, which might help for tracking bugs etc., or do you mean any other info window?

Comment: Yep, I meant the "Info Window" that shows, what's going on. I am used o the Maya Script editor, where you could see a LOT more what is going on under the hood. This enabled me to automate several selection, detection and scene-assessment procedures. But if the level of information is that low I will need to find oher ways.

Comment: Well, the Blender Manual on the _Infor Editor_ says only what the tooltip already said: _"The Info editor logs executed operators, warnings and error messages."_ So I don't think there is any way to level it up...